# android how to improve gradle build time?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

i have an Android project with following structure  -

Main Project with 4 module dependency -
each module in-turn has some aar dependencies which they get from maven repo.

the project is enabled for multi-dex.

now, whenever i make some even a single line java file change the app takes around 1:25 minutes to build the apk. ( the final apk is around 29MB ( just to give some idea on project size ) ).

I have enabled all gradle properties required to speed-up the build time.
i have specified the following properties in my main root gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

i see a lot of "UP-TO-DATE" messages when the app is building

```
:myApp:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132211Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton190Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComGithubFengdaiAlertdialogproCore023Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComGithubFengdaiAlertdialogproThemeMaterial023Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComJpardogoMaterialtabstripLibrary110Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComSothreeSlidinguppanelLibrary300Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareComTimehopStickyheadersrecyclerviewLibrary041Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareJpCoCyberagentAndroidGpuimageGpuimageLibrary123Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareOrgRajawali3dRajawali10255SNAPSHOTLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareUkCoChrisjenxCalligraphy210Library UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:prepareDevelopmentDebugDependencies
:myApp:compileDevelopmentDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:compileDevelopmentDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:mergeDevelopmentDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:generateDevelopmentDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:mergeDevelopmentDebugResources
:myApp:processDevelopmentDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:processDevelopmentDebugResources
:myApp:generateDevelopmentDebugSources
:myApp:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac
:myApp:compileDevelopmentDebugSources
:myApp:collectDevelopmentDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:myApp:packageAllDevelopmentDebugClassesForMultiDex
:myApp:shrinkDevelopmentDebugMultiDexComponents
:myApp:createDevelopmentDebugMainDexClassList
:myApp:dexDevelopmentDebug
```

it takes some time at the last step - myApp:dexDevelopmentDebug
i am specifying the following dexOptions in my build.gradle

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
```

is there any techniques to speed up the build times ? or is it the max i could achieve ?

any inputs is highly appreciated as it really hinders the productivity in testing even small changes to the app.

Thanks,